# Check letters in the string

Tags: python

How to check if the first three letters in the string are the same as three last letters reversed. They can't overlap. 
For example:

```
"karak" -> False
"kaakaak" -> True
```

Figured out that like this I can check out first three and last three reversed letters of string:

```
if s[:3] == s[-3:][::-1]:
```

But how to check if they are overlaping or not?

Comment: Why don’t you check the length of the string before you test?

Comment: The first 3 letters will overlap with the last 3 if the string is less than 6 characters long.

Comment: len(s) >= 6 and  s[:3] == s[-3:][::-1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking length and compare first 3 letters with last 3 letters:

```
is_equal = True if len(s) >= 6 and s[:3] == s[-3:][::-1] else False
```

Comment: shorter: `is_equal = len(s) >= 6 and s[:3] == s[-3:][::-1]`